# Invariant Violation: [7655,"RCTView",{"flexGrow":"<<NaN>>"}] is not usable as a native method argument

Tags: react-native

I got an error once video playing is complete I used for the react-native-video-player so please tell me how to correct that error

```
 <FlatList
                    numColumns={2}
                    data={this.state.studio}
                    renderItem={({item}) =><View style={{marginTop:10, marginLeft:10}}>
                      {item.IsAudio==1?(<View>
                        <Text>hii</Text>
                      </View>):(
                        <View>
                          <VideoPlayer
                           endWithThumbnail
                           video={{uri:""+IMAGE+""+item.MediaLink}}
                           videoWidth={200}
                           videoHeight={150}
                           resizeMode={'stretch'}
                        >
                     </VideoPlayer>
                        </View>
                      )}
                    </View>}
                    ></FlatList>
```

this is my code

Comment: What have you tried, please show us the code

Comment: i tried to play the video coming from API but the video is played after it shows the this error

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi please tell me how to clear this error

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi please tell me how to clear this error